# R: Manipulating dataframes

Tags: r

**Df_01a**

```
Name      re1 re2  re3       parameter
a         144 39.7 0.012     fed    
b         223 31.2     5     fed  
c         304 6.53   100     fed  
d         187 51.3    25     fed  
e         110 2.94   100     fed  
f         151 4.23    75     fed  
g         127 36.7 0.012     fed
```

**Df_01b**

```
Name      re1 re2  re3       parameter
a         142 39.3 0.042     feh    
b         221 31.0     4     feh  
c         301 6.13   90      feh  
d         185 41.3    15     feh  
e         107 2.44   940     feh  
f         143 2.23    75     feh  
g         121 31.7 0.012     feh
```

**Df_02**

```
parameter  c1    c2   c3
1  fed     5     4     3
2  feh     3     4     2
3  fea     5     4     3
4  few     2     4     3
```

**Desired result:**

```
c-value    re-value          name
5         142                a_fed 
4         39.3               a_fed 
3         0.042              a_fed
5         221                b_fed                           
4         31.0               b_fed
3         4                  b_fed
5         304                c_fed
4         6.53               c_fed
3        100                 c_fed
....
3        0.012               g_fed
3        142                 a_feh
4        39.3                a_feh
2        0.042               a_feh
3        221                 b_feh
4        31.0                b_feh
2         4                  b_feh
....
```

1. I have `Df_01a, Df_01b, Df_01c, Df_01d`. These have a parameter in
   column 5: `fed, feh,  fea, few`, respectively (See `Df_02`).
2. Each parameter has 3 values, given by `c1`, `c2` and `c3` in `Df_02`.

How can I get the desired data.frame shown above?

Comment: It's not super clear to me what you want but I get that you probably want to reshape these data frames and merge them? If so, [this article](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) probably has what you want.

Comment: I think your expected output is wrong, `142` is a `feh` value, not `fed`, all `feh` and `fed` are inverted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**code**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
rbind(Df_01a,Df_01b) %>% gather("re-col","re-value",c("re1","re2","re3")) %>%
  inner_join(Df_02 %>% rename(re1=c1,re2=c2,re3=c3) %>% gather("re-col","c-value",c("re1","re2","re3"))) %>%
  arrange(parameter,Name) %>%
  unite(name,Name,parameter) %>%
  select(`c-value`,`re-value`,`name`)
```

**result**

```
#    c-value re-value  name
# 1        5  144.000 a_fed
# 2        4   39.700 a_fed
# 3        3    0.012 a_fed
# 4        5  223.000 b_fed
# 5        4   31.200 b_fed
# 6        3    5.000 b_fed
# 7        5  304.000 c_fed
# 8        4    6.530 c_fed
# 9        3  100.000 c_fed
# 10       5  187.000 d_fed
# 11       4   51.300 d_fed
# 12       3   25.000 d_fed
# 13       5  110.000 e_fed
# 14       4    2.940 e_fed
# 15       3  100.000 e_fed
# 16       5  151.000 f_fed
# 17       4    4.230 f_fed
# 18       3   75.000 f_fed
# 19       5  127.000 g_fed
# 20       4   36.700 g_fed
# 21       3    0.012 g_fed
# 22       3  142.000 a_feh
# 23       4   39.300 a_feh
# 24       2    0.042 a_feh
# 25       3  221.000 b_feh
# 26       4   31.000 b_feh
# 27       2    4.000 b_feh
# 28       3  301.000 c_feh
# 29       4    6.130 c_feh
# 30       2   90.000 c_feh
# 31       3  185.000 d_feh
# 32       4   41.300 d_feh
# 33       2   15.000 d_feh
# 34       3  107.000 e_feh
# 35       4    2.440 e_feh
# 36       2  940.000 e_feh
# 37       3  143.000 f_feh
# 38       4    2.230 f_feh
# 39       2   75.000 f_feh
# 40       3  121.000 g_feh
# 41       4   31.700 g_feh
# 42       2    0.012 g_feh
```

**data**

```
Df_01a <- read.table(text="Name      re1 re2  re3       parameter
a         144 39.7 0.012     fed    
                     b         223 31.2     5     fed  
                     c         304 6.53   100     fed  
                     d         187 51.3    25     fed  
                     e         110 2.94   100     fed  
                     f         151 4.23    75     fed  
                     g         127 36.7 0.012     fed",header=T,stringsAsFactors=F)

Df_01b  <- read.table(text="Name      re1 re2  re3       parameter
                      a         142 39.3 0.042     feh    
                      b         221 31.0     4     feh  
                      c         301 6.13   90      feh  
                      d         185 41.3    15     feh  
                      e         107 2.44   940     feh  
                      f         143 2.23    75     feh  
                      g         121 31.7 0.012     feh",header=T,stringsAsFactors=F)

Df_02  <- read.table(text="parameter  c1    c2   c3
                     1  fed     5     4     3
                     2  feh     3     4     2
                     3  fea     5     4     3
                     4  few     2     4     3",header=T,stringsAsFactors=F)
```